# is there a way to order a the return of a serializer? django rest framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization

Is there a way to order a serializer in djano rest framework?

```
class VenueImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VenueImage
        # psuedo code: orderby = 'order' <--- something like this?
        fields = ('pk','imageurl', 'venue', 'key', 'order')
```

Comment: You should override **`to_representation()`** see this SO post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317046/how-to-order-django-rest-framework-queryset-from-serializer-field

Comment: Just curious : Any  special reason to do it in serializer? why not order the data before serializing them ? In such case, your serializer can be used everywhere and you don't need special serializer if you dont want to order data by 'order'.